# Database schema design for records of nested JSON

Tags: sql, database, json, database-design, nosql

I have a list of `profile` records, which each of the record is like the below:

```
{
  "name": "Peter Pan",
  "contacts": [
    {
      "key": "mobile",
      "value": "1234-5678"
    }
  ],
  "addresses": [
    {
      "key": "postal",
      "value": "2356 W. Manchester Ave.\nSomewhere District\nA Country"
    },
    {
      "key": "po",
      "value": "PO Box 1234"
    }
  ],
  "emails": [
    {
      "key": "work",
      "value": "abc@work.com"
    },
    {
      "key": "personal",
      "value": "abc@personal.com"
    }
  ],
  "url": "http://www.example.com/"
}
```

I would think about having the following schema structure:

1. A `profile` table with `id` and `name` field.
2. A `profile_contact` table with `id`, `profile_id`, `key`, `value` field.
3. A `profile_address` table with `id`, `profile_id`, `key`, `value` field.
4. A `profile_email` table with `id`, `profile_id`, `key`, `value` field.

However, I think I am creating too many tables for such a simple JSON!

1. Would there be performance problems when I search across the tables, since many JOINS are performed to retrieve just one record?
2. What would be a better way to model the above JSON record into the database? In SQL, or better in NoSQL?

Comment: you cannot design "nested" column in a table in sql.

Comment: @DerekFloss, not in one table, probably several tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It kind of depends.
If you are planning to have an "infinite" amount of contacts/addresses/emails per user then your idea is a pretty good way to go.

You could also consider (something like) the following:

**PROFILE** table, containing:

- `PROFILE_ID`
- `NAME`
- `EMAIL_ADDRESS_WORK`
- `EMAIL_ADDRESS_PERSONAL`
- `PHONE_NUMBER`
- `MOBILE_NUMBER`

**ADDRESS** table, containing:

- `ADDRESS_ID`
- `PROFILE_ID`
- `STREET`
- `CITY`
- ..etc

This means you can set 2 kinds of emails and 2 kinds of phone numbers per user and they are stored with the profile itself.

Alternatively you can choose to have a separate **CONTACT** table which contains both phone numbers and email addresses (and maybe other types):

- `CONTACT_TYPE` (phone, mobile, email_work, email_personal)
- `CONTACT_VALUE`
- `PROFILE_ID`

All three (mine, and yours) could work perfectly. To better decide what would work for you, you should write down all possibilities there are (and could be). Maybe you want to be able to add 10 email addresses per profile (then storing them with the profile would be silly), maybe you will have a very large variaty in different contact types, such as IM, facebook, ICQ, twitter (then a CONTACTS table would fit nicely).

So try to find out/list what types of data you will have and see how that will fit into a specific model, then pick the most suitable one :)

Answer (score -1):

This is the most common case for database design... You should stop threading it as something new just because you included json :-)

Just create

User: id, name

Contacts: user-id, id, key, value

Email and addresses and whatever else is like contacts.

Now you just have to select from user and inner join the other tables on user.id=id